# Python Threading Not Working as it supposed

Tags: python

So i have a function and i want to run this function several times with different args it should be like this right

```
def a(arg):
  print(arg)
a(arg1)
a(arg2)
a(arg3)
a(arg4)
```

but with threading we can just do this

```
def a(arg):
  print(arg)
args = ["arg1","arg2","arg3","arg4"]
for arg in args:
t = threading.Thread(target=a, args = (arg, ))
t.start()
```

in my original code there are 50 other args and when i start my code it just starts 20 of them and after a while it just decreases to 3 or 1 or 2 it doesn't matter it just decreases and never goes back to normal why would it be like this

Comment: Hi. Considering that you say your original code is different, have you been able to create a [mcve] that is as simple as possible but with the same problem? (Sometimes just creating this already helps me to find a solution to my own question). Sidenote: your code snippet that you posted here has wrong indentation

Comment: I can just paste my code here if it's necessary? and i also changed wrong indentation

Comment: The point would be that you take your code and remove stuff that is not related to the problem until you end up with something very simple that you can paste here (I assume the full code is longer than necessary). The cool thing about that is that often just trying to simplify it will fix the issue, and then you know what made the difference. Also, having an example that fails is helpful because otherwise we can only guess what might be wrong in your code that is correct here.

Comment: I doubt that you fixed the indentation though? the `for arg in args` does not have any loop content the way it is right now

Answer (score 0):

You have some identation problems (and forgot to change the target) in your code, but this example works fine for me

```
import threading

def a(arg):
  print(arg)

args = []
for i in range(50):
  args.append("arg" + str(i))

for arg in args:
  t = threading.Thread(target=a, args=(arg, ))
  t.start()
```

This prints out

```
arg0
arg1
arg2
...
arg49
```

Comment: I don't know how but a simple code like u wrote can work but in my code it gets and information from API at first i thought it is because of api but it seems it isn't so i still have no answer

Comment: @Theproblemguy does your function modify something that other threads might simultaneously use? That is a common cause of threading bug

Answer (score 0):

I really highly recommend using a threadpool for this sort of stuff.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


with ThreadPool() as pool:
    pool.map(a, args)
```

Comment: Can u teach me differences between threadpool and creating threads like i did in my code

Comment: Hmm.  Current documentation says to use `ProcessPoolExecutor()` instead.  But the resulting code is nearly identical.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor